# Setting the disabled property based either of the two boolean variables

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am currently trying to set the disabled property to true or false based on value of a flag in my angular 7 application. How do I set the value based on either of the two flags as it is giving me a runtime error

As you can see below I am assigning the following

```
   [disabled] =  CanEditManagerStrategy
```

Code

```
 <div *ngIf="EditMode[f.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel.Id]">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn" style="float: left;"
               [disabled] =  CanEditManagerStrategy
               (click)="reviewClicked(f.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel.Id,1)">Review
                                                Terms</button>
             <div style="float: left; margin: 5px;">
                       {{f.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel.AuditSummary}}
            </div>
  </div>
```

I need to check against two values and trying the following which is giving an error

```
 [disabled] =  CanEditManagerStrategy || CanEdit
```

Comment: Please post the runtime error.

Comment: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '||' is not a valid attribute name.

Comment: i think he forgot the "" because on stackblitz [disabled]="CanEditManagerStrategy || CanEdit"  works as expected

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it with "" , tried to reproduce

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ri29rm

```
[disabled] = "CanEditManagerStrategy || CanEdit"
```

Comment: There is a small change in the requirement. I need to set disabled to false if the CanEdit is false and disabled to true if CanEditManagerStrategy is true

Comment: you can change to CanEditManagerStrategy || !CanEdit, if you want both condition change to CanEditManagerStrategy && !CanEdit